# I can't get triangle to switch rotation directions

Tags: c, opengl

I have looked over this code many times and can't figure out why it doesn't work. I'm increasing a variable and creating a transformation matrix out of it to rotate a triangle around the z axis. Here is my code.

```
void rotate()
{   
    if(zaxis <= -360)
    {
        zaxis = 0;
        cw = true;
        ccw = false;
    }
    else if(zaxis >= 360)
    {
        zaxis = 0;
        cw = false;
        ccw = true;
    }   
    matrixz[0] = cos(zaxis);
    matrixz[1] = sin(zaxis);
    matrixz[4] = (-1) * sin(zaxis);
    matrixz[5] = cos(zaxis);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixloc, 1, GL_FALSE, matrixz);

    if (cw)
        zaxis += 0.01;
    else if (ccw)
        zaxis -= 0.01;
}
```

I set `cw` to true and `ccw` to false originally. The triangle rotates fine in one direction but doesn't change directions when it rotates past 360 or -360. I'm not sure if this is just a C problem or an OpenGL problem. Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: `cos()` and `sin()` accept parameter in radian instead of degree.

Comment: Also, you'll notice that `cw = !ccw` so you can get rid of `ccw` entirely.

Comment: Why not `matrixz[4] = -sin(zaxis);`?